# Is possible create data faster?

Tags: zikula

I have an application how this:

[image]

If i have that add each answer one to one (and select the question), the process for the user is very hard.

Is it possible create with MOST a new process more faster and easy for the user? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider removing the whole answer entity and adding an array field to the question instead?